# Scheduling tasks in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-scheduler

I'm building an application on `Laravel 5.7` where I'm having a cron job to run following commands:

```
$schedule->command('telescope:clear')->timezone('Asia/Kolkata')->dailyAt('24:00');
$schedule->command('backup:clean')->timezone('Asia/Kolkata')->dailyAt('01:00');
$schedule->command('backup:run')->timezone('Asia/Kolkata')->dailyAt('01:30');
```

But this continously throws an exception which I found out in telescope:

[image: cronjob error]

Also the location states:

[image: location trace]

I don't know what is the mistake I'm doing I want to run command in midnight and then do a backup after one hour of clearing telescope entries. Help me out with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such time as `24:00`. Use `00:00` instead.

Comment: Silly mistake...:)